# How do I run some custom code when the user cancels a workflow?

Tags: 2010, workflow, visual-studio

That's basically the whole question. We need to be able to react -- preferably instantly -- in the event a Sharepoint workflow is canceled by a user. (Have to send some emails, update some database records, etc. Long story.)

How can we do that? I was thinking, for the lack of a better way, to create a timer job with a 1-minute interval that queries all of our list items, gets the associated workflows and checks their status. This would put a HUGE additional load on our servers, though, and an event-based solution would probably be best.

Comment: Is this an out of the box WF created in SharePoint Designer or WF made in Visual Studio?

Comment: Visual Studio. Sorry, updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement your [SPWorkflowEventReceiver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee556021.aspx) and put your code in one of the handlers of this class (I do not remember which handler is invoked on cansel action).

Comment: There is none :-( The events I can handle are "started", "completed" and "postponed".

Comment: I have another idea ) Could you add event handler to the workflow history list. If you cancel a workflow I hope a new item is added to this list and one of this item filed contains "cancel" status, other fields should contain information about workflow )

Comment: You, sir, are a genius.